# I am unable to handle state correctly on Safari due to the useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am having issues on Safari when updating the state of a component. I understand that Safari is suppose to have a more Strict Mode than Chrome but in this case I am stuck on this bug.

I have these inputs:

[image]

The issue is that every time I select an option of the dropdown, it removes the value of the other input. Like in this case, I selected January and then the other input got back to its default value `N/A`.

On Chrome and Firefox this works correctly. The issue is only on Safari.

See some code:

```js
let birthDays: number[] = [0];
const [birthDayState, setBirthDays] = useState(birthDays);
// userDetails is an object/prop which holds all of the information of a user
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({} as typeof userDetails);

const handleBirthMonthChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent): void => {
    const { value, name } = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    setUserInput({ ...userInput, [name]: value });
    setBirthDays(loadDays(year, value));
};

const handleDayChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const field = event.target.name;
    console.log({ field });
    setUserInput({ ...userInput, [field]: event.target.value });
};

return (
  <GetToKnowMeForm              
    birthDates={birthDayState}
    birthDay={userInput?.birthday}
    birthMonth={userInput?.birthMonth}
    handleBirthMonthChange={handleBirthMonthChange}              
    handleChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleDayChange(e)}
  />
)
```

So I am wondering where am I failing at. Any insights on this?
I realized that on this function the method `loadDays`:

```js
const handleBirthMonthChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent): void => {
    const { value, name } = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    setUserInput({ ...userInput, [name]: value });
    setBirthDays(loadDays(year, value));
};
```

Is the one failing, this is how it looks:

```js
export const fullDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31];

export const loadDays = (year: number, month?: string): number[] => {
  if (month) {
    if (year === undefined || year === null) { year = new Date().getFullYear(); }

    const currentMonth = monthByDate(new Date(`${month}/${year}`));
    const date = new Date(year, currentMonth, 1);
    const days = [];
    while (date.getMonth() === currentMonth) {
      days.push(new Date(date).getDate());
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return days;
  } else {
    return fullDays;
  }
};
```

Can you tell why?

Answer (score 0):

I see there is on small mistake in `handleBirthMonthChange`. You are calling set state 2 time. As rule, you should not update 2 state once. Since setState is async. You can merge the state and try.

It could be a potential issue of unpredictable behavior.

```
const [userDetail, setUserDetail] = useState({
  birthDays: [0],
  userInput: {}
});
const { birthDays, userInput } = userDetail;
const handleBirthMonthChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent): void => {
  const { value, name } = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
  setUserDetail({
    birthDays: loadDays(year, value),
    userInput: { ...userInput, [name]: value }
  });
};

const handleDayChange = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
): void => {
  const field = event.target.name;
  setUserDetail({
    birthDays,
    userInput: { ...userInput, [field]: event.target.value }
  });
};

return (
  <GetToKnowMeForm
    birthDates={birthDayState}
    birthDay={userInput?.birthday}
    birthMonth={userInput?.birthMonth}
    handleBirthMonthChange={handleBirthMonthChange}
    handleChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
      handleDayChange(e)
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: Can you show some code to express better your idea?